# How to use HttpContext inside Task.Run

Tags: async-await, task-parallel-library

There is some posts explain how to tackle, but couldnt help me much..
Logging Request/Response in middleware, it works when use 'await' with Task.Run() but since its awaited current operation to complete there is performance issue.

When I remove await as below, it runs fast but not logging anything, since HttpContext instance not available to use inside parallel thread

```
public class LoggingHandlerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly ILoggerManager _loggerManager;

        public LoggingHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerManager loggerManager)
        {
            this.next = next;
            _loggerManager = loggerManager;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILoggerManager loggerManager, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
                _ = Task.Run(() =>
                  {
                      AdvanceLoggingAsync(context, _loggerManager, environment);
                  });
              ...
        }

        private void AdvanceLoggingAsync(HttpContext context, ILoggerManager loggerManager, IWebHostEnvironment environment, bool IsResponse = false)
            {
                 {
                    context.Request.EnableBuffering(); // Throws ExecutionContext.cs not found
                    result += $"ContentType:{context.Request.ContentType},";

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
                    {
                        result += $"Body:{await reader.ReadToEndAsync()}";
                        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                    }
                    loggerManager.LogInfo($"Advance Logging Content(Request)-> {result}");
            }
```

How can I leverage Task.Run() performance with accessing HttpContext?

Comment: Why do you need to run your `AdvanceLoggingAsync` via `Task.Run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can extract what you need from the context, build your string you want to log, and then pass that string to the task you run.

However, firing and forgetting a task is not good.  If it throws an exception, you risk of bringing down the server, or at least you will have very hard time getting information about the error.

If you are concerned about the logging performance, better add what you need to log to a message queue, and have a process that responds to new messages in the queue and logs the message to the log file.